# Unable to connect mysql nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm trying to connect remote server MySQL database from another test server 
from my rest API using node js.

My database connection.js

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var poolConnection = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit : 100,
    host            : 'xx.xx.xx.xxx',
    port            : 3306,
    user            : 'testuser', 
    password        : 'test123',
    socketPath      : '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
});

exports.query = function(sql,args,callback){
    poolConnection.query(sql,args,callback);    
}
```

While trying to run the query from my API I'm getting this error :

```
{ Error: connect ENOENT /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1043:20)
at PipeConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1090:14)
----------------------------
code: 'ENOENT',
errno: 'ENOENT',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock',
fatal: true }
```

From many another StackOverflow reference, I also try to comment out bind-address but there is also not any success. How to solve this problem.

Comment: Your Socket path is wrong, I'd assume. Try to resolve it with ``require('path')`` first.

Comment: @Crowes remote server my.cnf file show same path for socket = '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For connections to a remote MySQL server, leave out the `socketPath` option, because that only makes sense if the MySQL server is running on the same host as your application.

This does require that the MySQL server is set up to allow connections over TCP.

Comment: but without socket path getting a connection refused error `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED xx.xx.xx.xxx:3306`

Comment: @sasuke that's why I wrote: _"This does require that the MySQL server is set up to allow connections over TCP."_ Also, your server needs to allow incoming connections to port 3306 (which also means you have to think about security implications of opening up a port to the outside world).